# SAS - Why it is displaying the values of len1 to len3 as 12 in output

Tags: sas

Why it is displaying the values of len1 to len3 as 12 in output?

```
data champ;
array len[4] len1-len4;
do i = 1 to 4;  
len[i] = lengthn(len[i]); 
end;
run;
```

Comment: The behaviour is explained in the documentation for [lengthn](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002284668.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Because you used a character function on a numeric variable. So SAS converted the number to a character string and reported the length of the generated string. You should have seen this note in the SAS log.

> NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the
>   places given by:

By default SAS will use `BEST12.` format to convert the numbers to a string. Hence the returned value was always 12 characters long.